# Apache hive-metastore standalone showing error "Kerberos principal should have 3 parts:"

Tags: hive-metastore

I am deploying hive-metastore-3.0.0 using kerberos  over DC/OS I have generated principal and keytab correctly and verified the same but while providing repective settings in `metastore-site.xml` still server showing error "Kerberos principal should have 3 parts:" its by default pickup my user "nobody or root" by which I run service but not the principal.
Rquest you to please help is there any addition property I have to set ?

My `metastore-site.xml` is:

````
        <name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
        <description>If true, the metastore thrift interface will be secured with SASL. Clients must authenticate with Kerberos.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file</name>
        <value>hive-metastore.keytab</value>
        <description>The path to the Kerberos Keytab file containing the metastore thrift server's service principal.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.principal</name>
        <value>hive-metastore/node-0-server.hive-metastore.autoip.dcos.thisdcos.directory@LOCAL</value>
        <description>The service principal for the metastore thrift server. The special string _HOST will be replaced automatically with the correct host name.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.authentication</name>
        <value>KERBEROS</value>
        <description>authenticationtype</description>     
    </property>```
````

Comment: Are you sure that the XML file you show is really used by the Metastore service? Did you raise the Log4J  level to `DEBUG` or `TRACE` to get more details about the configuration that is picked at startup?

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter for reply yes I enabled the same by below property:
```logger.HiveMetaStore.name = org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore
logger.HiveMetaStore.level = DEBUG```

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter may this log output will lead you to guide me something ```Key: <metastore.catalog.default> old hive key: <metastore.catalog.default>  value: <hive>
Key: <metastore.client.kerberos.principal> old hive key: <hive.metastore.client.kerberos.principal>  value: <>```

Comment: and ```Key: <metastore.kerberos.keytab.file> old hive key: <hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file>  value: <hive-metastore.keytab>
Key: <metastore.kerberos.principal> old hive key: <hive.metastore.kerberos.principal>  value: <hive-metastore/node-0-server.hive-metastore.autoip.dcos.thisdcos.directory@LOCAL>```

Comment: By the way: properties such as "authentication type" and "Metastore SPN" _(Kerberos service principal name)_ are used by **both** server and client. Before Hive 3.0 they should have been stored in the generic `hive-site.xml` while only the properties that are specific to the service (e.g.  the keytab) would have gone to `hive-metastore.site`. With Hive 3 I see that the service gets its own `metastore.xml` with its private props + a copy of generic props. All right. But don't forget to make generic props available to clients (i.e. HS2, Spark)

Comment: _"server showing error "_ >> is it really the _Metastore_ service that logs an error? does it log the error on startup, i.e. when using its own properties, or when a client tries to connect, i.e. using its client-side properties to get a service ticket for whatever it thinks is the Metatsore SPN?

Comment: it log the error on startup, when using its own properties.

Comment: I also notice that its not using kerberos as user or auth see the log:
```security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login

security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login commit

security.UserGroupInformation: using local user:UnixPrincipal: nobody

security.UserGroupInformation: Using user: "UnixPrincipal: nobody" with name nobody

security.UserGroupInformation: User entry: "nobody"

security.UserGroupInformation: UGI loginUser:nobody (auth:SIMPLE)
```
its using local user i.e. `nobody` or `root`

Comment: Did you set up a `core-site.xml` with Kerberos auth? The Hadoop-Auth library might use that as a kind of global switch...

Comment: Yes @SamsonScharfrichter I set the related properties there also